# Regex with multiple newlines in sequence

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use PHP's split() (preg_split() is also an option if your answer works with it) to split up a string on 2 or more `\r\n`'s. My current effort is:

```
split("(\r\n){2,}",$nb);
```

The problem with this is it matches every time there is 2 or 3 `\r\n`'s, then goes on and finds the next one. This is ineffective with 4 or more `\r\n`'s.

I need all instances of two or more `\r\n`'s to be treated the same as two `\r\n`'s. For example, I'd need

```
Hello\r\n\r\nMy\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nName is\r\nShadow
```

to become

```
array('Hello','My','Name is\r\nShadow');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag to preg_replace() with Tomalak's pattern of `"/(\\r\\n){2,}/"` accomplished this for me.

Answer (score 3):

`preg_split()` *should* do it with

```
$pattern = "/(\\r\\n){2,}/";
```

Comment: yes, because pcre works "greedy" by default i.e. {2,} tries to match as many characters as possible while split() will stop the pattern matching as soon as it's fulfilled.

Comment: It didn't do it with just that, but I found the PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY flag which accomplishes the same thing for my purposes.

Comment: @chendral: Hm... @Gumbo's answer seems to indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following suggestion:

$nb = implode("\r\n", array_filter(explode("\r\n", $nb)));

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
$nb = "Hello\r\n\r\nMy\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nName is\r\nShadow";
$parts = split("(\r\n){2,}",$nb);
var_dump($parts);
var_dump($parts === array('Hello','My',"Name is\r\nShadow"));
```

Prints:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "My"
  [2]=>
  string(15) "Name is
Shadow"
}
bool(true)
```

Note the [double quotes](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) in the second test to get the characters represented by `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

`\R` is shorthand for matching newline sequences across different operating systems.  You can prevent empty elements being created at the start and end of your output array by using the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag or you could call `trim()` on the string before splitting.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/R02jh))

```
$string = "\r\n\r\nHello\r\n\r\nMy\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nName is\r\nShadow\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";

var_export(preg_split('~\R{2,}~', $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));

echo "\n---\n";

var_export(preg_split('~\R{2,}~', trim($string)));
```

Output from either technique:

```
array (
  0 => 'Hello',
  1 => 'My',
  2 => 'Name is
Shadow',
)
```